# My EditText seems to be blocked. How can I "unblock" it?

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I was making an Android Studio project, and one of my EditTexts seems to be blocked when I run the app, I click it, but it doesn't focus and I can't edit it. In the java programming, I was trying to make this vertical LinearLayour appear programically when the user press the Button btnVacina, but when it appear, I can only edit the EditText edtDoses, and I can see the content inside the EditText edtData (which is the one that seems to bwe blocked), but I cant focus or edit it.

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNomeVacina"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDescricaoVacina"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvNomeVacina"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnVacina"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="+"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lyVacina"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#2400FF"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Data de Aplicação da Vacina: " />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtData"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:text="11/11/1111"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Quantidade de Doses: " />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtDoses"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnEnviar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enviar"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: are you sure you are not disabling it programmatically? BTW you don't need to explicitly say that it is enabled. Maybe you should post the entire layout xml

Comment: I coudn't find anywhere in my code where I could possibly be disabling it, and I edited the question and posted the entire XML

Comment: Please check your Java/Kotlin code it may have disabled in program

Comment: It does not look like you posted your entire XML any way the wrap content does not seem correct for an edit text. Can you try with match_parent for the width?

Comment: Did you check if you ever put the layout (id: lyVacina) into visible mode? Also, did you check if you somewhere disable that layout? If a layout is disabled, it's childs are disabled as well.

Comment: I tried to use match_parent, but I got the same result. Also I checked my code, and I put the layout in visible mode, and I there is no point where I disable it programically

Comment: Only thing I can suggest is post whole code, otherwise there is no way for us to guess the reason

Comment: I tried to post the whole code, but StackOverflow says my question contains mainly code, and doesn't let me post it. Is there an easy and safe way to show the whole code?

Comment: you can tag people with @ so they get notified you replied to them if you want a faster reply. Anyway, I don't know if there's an easy way to do it, maybe start with the whole xml file and we will continue from there?

Comment: @DanBaruch thanks for te tip, and I edited the question and put the whole XML in it

Comment: The XML seems fine tbh. Seems like its somewhere in the code